# How can I log terminal output to a file but leave the terminal window active to allow answering of prompts?

Tags: command-line, logging

I am trying to run a big script that prompts for answers along the way. I want to run it in verbose mode and thus there will be significant output and I'd like to capture it.  Therefore I'd like to run it in a way that allows me to answer the questions as well as sending the output to a file.

Can this be done ?

Thanks.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

While answering you are giving input via file descriptor 0 i.e. STDIN and the program is showing output on file descriptor 1 i.e. STDOUT. As you can see these two are wowking on different file descriptors and manipulating one should not hamper the operation of other.

Note that there is also file descriptor 2 i.e. STDERR normally used for showing error messages.

In you case run the script as:

```
./myscript.sh >~/script.out
```

Now you can provide input answers to the questions of the script via STDIN and the output of the program will be saved in `~/script.out`.

You can save the error also e.g. in another file:

```
./myscript.sh >~/script.out 2>~/script.err
```

The STDOUT will be saved in `~/script.out` and the STDERR will be saved in `~/script.err`.

You can save the output and error both in the same file:

```
./myscript.sh >~/script.all 2>&1
```

Now `~/script.all` will contain the outputs and error messages (if any) from `myscript.sh`.